# How to disable a custom function in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a function called 'function test(){}' in a script (which I don't have access to). Now how do I remove/disable that function using another script?

Comment: Context would help. In what scope is that function? If it's on the global scope you could simply override it. or if it is a method on a public API. If it's a private function then no you can't.

Comment: if it is global, than just redefine it... If it is not in a scope you can access, than there is not much you can do.

Comment: why down voted? :(  Its just a simple question. -_-

Comment: ppl are downvoting because "disabling a function" is never the correct solution for any problem in javascript.

Comment: You haven't answered the first comment asking for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the function is global, you can overwrite the reference to it with something else (`null` for example):

```
test = null;
```

If it's not global, but instead hidden away inside a scoping function, you probably can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *disable* a function, but you can still set it to `null` or declare it again the way you want if you want to ensure compatibility `function test() { return; }`, if you have access to it of course.